# custom url to display content from database in custom form in drupal 7

Tags: php, forms, drupal

I created custom form in drupal 7 and data is saved in a table called "person" in database when i am trying to retrieve data in custom url data is displaying but when loading the form page "page not found" message is displaying not getting that form, if the code for retrieve data in custom url is commented then i get form page.
this is the code which i used:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Provides a custom form, data are saved in database and can retrieve data in table format in custom url.
 */


//Implementation of hook_menu()
function form_test_menu() {
  $items['formtest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form Test',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_test_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

    $items = array();
    $items['results'] = array( // change to the url you want
    'title' => 'results',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'results',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
return $items;
}

//function to describe field in the form
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
    $form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 'Enter Your Name',//make this field required 
    );
    $form['address']['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('E-mail'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#maxlength' => 255,
    ); 
    $form['price'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => 'What is Your Price?',
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
    );
    $form['attending'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Will you be attending?'),
    '#options' => array(
    '1'   => t('Yes'),
    '0' => t('No'),
    ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => isset($attending) ? $attending : NULL,
    );  

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    );
    return $form;
}

//validation code for integer 
function form_test_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!($form_state['values']['price'] > 0)){
    form_set_error('price', t('Price must be a positive number.'));
  }
}
//inserting data into database
drupal_write_record('person', $data);
function form_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $id = db_insert('person')
    ->fields(array(
      'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
      'email' => $form_state['values']['email'],
      'price' => $form_state['values']['price'],
      'attending' => $form_state['values']['attending'],
     // 'ios' => $form_state['values']['ios'],
  ))
  ->execute();
  drupal_set_message(t('data saved successfully.'));
}
//Retrieving data from database
function results() {
    print "CUSTOM TABLE CONTENT";
    print "<br /> ";
    print "<br /> ";
    $query = db_select('person', 'u');
    $query->fields('u', array('name'));  //mention the field that you want to display
    $query->fields('u', array('email')); 
    $query->fields('u', array('price')); 
    $query->fields('u', array('attending')); 
    $result = $query->execute();
        while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {  //while loop mention how the data want to display
            echo "<li>";
            print_r($record['name']);
            print " ";
            print_r($record['email']);
            print " ";
            print_r($record['price']);
            print " ";
            print_r($record['attending']);
            echo "</li>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$items = array();
 this code should be come under the main function 
function form_test_menu() {
the code should be like this

```
function form_test_menu() {
 $items = array();
```

no other modification it will work.